# How to backup database phonegap / cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, backup

I was wondering if someone could explain me how to backup database from my application. I build this app using Phonegap.

Thank you

Comment: By backup do you mean a physical copy on device or a backup off device?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Already solved. I built my own plugin for it.

Comment: Please give us the details of what tools you used to solve your issue.

Comment: I just made my own plugin, it's not that hard with Cordova's documentation. My plugin just created a copy of the database.

Comment: Can u please paste the code here pls.. Actually I have the same requirement.. I need to store and replace db file from device.. Can you please help me to solve this..

Comment: @user1510494, we also need some hints. Can you please share your idea with us